# Programmatically click href link using setInterval after x seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple 3 page demo site that I want try and get displaying in a similar manner to a Microsoft Powerpoint presentation.

So when the user manually clicks the "Start" link on the homepage, they move to page 2 that contains a value on the page of "4" (seconds) this value is inserted into the setInterval function in the page which then automatically clicks the "Next" link on the page after 4 seconds and takes the user to to page 3. Page 3 then loops back to the homepage after "6" seconds (as that value is again inserted into the setInterval function within the page)

Here is the setInterval timer code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.querySelector(".o-controls".click();
}, 3000)
```

Here is the code for the 3 pages:

```
<!--Homepage-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="start">
    <p>Click "Start" manually to start a Powerpoint style on pages 2 and 3</p>
    <a href="/page2.html">Start</a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>

<!--Page 2-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="page2">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Javascript function clicks "Next" link after value in seconds below:</p>
      <p id="secondsValue">4</p>
    </div>
    <a class="nextPage" href="/page3.html">Next</a>
  </section>
  <!-- Insert the #secondsValue into the setInterval function, rather than it's current static 4000 value-->
  setInterval(function () {
    document.querySelector("a.nextPage".click();
}, 4000)
</body>

</html>

<!--Page 3-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="page2">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Javascript function clicks "Next" link after value in seconds below. This then loops you back to the Homepage.</p>
      <p id="secondsValue">6</p>
    </div>
    <a class="nextPage" href="/homepage.html">Next</a>
  </section>
  <!-- Insert the #secondsValue into the setInterval function, rather than it's current static 6000 value-->
  setInterval(function () {
    document.querySelector("a.nextPage".click();
}, 6000)
</body>

</html>
```

How can I insert the seconds value stored within an element on the page into the setInterval function?

Comment: `setInterval(..., Number(document.querySelector('#secondsValue').textContent) * 1000);`

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis. `document.querySelector("a.nextPage").click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelector` and `.innerText` to get value, and `parseInt()` to convert it to integer and multiply it after:

```
var seconds = parseInt(document.querySelector("#secondsValue").innerText)*1000;      
 setInterval(function () {
document.querySelector("a.nextPage").click();

}, seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks niklaz, shouldn't that ```4000``` value be a dynamic value, rather than static? As it is the result of the varying value in ```#secondsValue```

Comment: @CWilliamson, apologies, yes, I have fixed the code.